# iOS互換性表記の指定方法

Tags: monaca

MonacaからリリースビルドしたiOSアプリで
App Storeの情報で互換性の「iOS *.*以降。」のバージョンを変更したいのですが
どのような設定をすれば変更する事が出来るのでしょうか。

Cordovaはバージョン5.2です。

Answer (score 1):

`MonacaApp-Info.plist`を編集しましょう
下記のように記載すれば最小の対応OSを指定できます。

```
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>4.1</string>
```

[参考](http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/reference/config/ios_configuration/)

Comment: .plist内で直接MinimumOSVersionを指定するのはやめたほうがよさそうです。https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html

Answer (score 0):

config.xmlに以下のようにdeployment-targetを指定してください。

対応OS8.0以上の場合
`<preference name="deployment-target" value="8.0" />`